# Subscribe catching response but not catching bad request 400 code error from http response

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient, subscribe

I have an input element for filename and file as below. Whenever the file gets uploaded, a toast message will be put out like "Inventory created successfully"

[image]

If the inventory name already exists, 400 bad requests error get thrown in browser console as below.

```
 POST http://192.168.119.107:8085/api/inventories/uploadFile 400 (Bad Request)
```

HTTP response got in the browser for the above API call

```
{
  "entityName" : "networkmanagerAnsibleinventory",
  "errorKey" : "nameexists",
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Inventory already exists",
  "status" : 400,
  "message" : "error.nameexists",
  "params" : "networkmanagerinventory"
}
```

In the below code, error part not get captured, so the toast message for 400 bad requests not displayed.

inventories.component.ts

```
uploadFile(e) {
    this.errorMessage = "";
    if (this.selectedFiles != null && this.inventoryname) {
      this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
      let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
      formdata.append('file', this.currentFileUpload);
      formdata.append('inventoryName', this.inventoryname);
      this.restservice.create('api/inventories/uploadFile', formdata)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.toast.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Inventory created successfully'
          });
         },
         err => {
          console.log('oops',err);
          if(err.status == 400){
            console.log("incoming");
            this.toast.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: err.error.title
              
            });
          }else{
            this.toast.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Error while uploading inventory'
            });
          }
        })
    }else{
      if(!this.selectedFiles){
        this.toast.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Choose file...'
        });
      }else{
        this.toast.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Name cannot be empty'
        });
      }
    }
    
  }
```

restservice.create

```
public create(route: string, body) {
    
    return this.http.post(this.createCompleteRoute(route, environment.urlAddress), body,{
      headers:this.getAuthHeader()
    });
  }
```

How to get the error captured and show toast message according to API response?

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: can you show me the           console.log('oops',err);

Comment: actually the console not all printing in browser

Comment: Can you poste restservice.create function

Comment: added create function in the question, sorry I should have added earlier.